# Can we call a function inside a routine where the function return data type is void?

Tags: c, function, void

For example, I have:

```
void(temperature, pressure,time)
{
    int i;
    double results[10];

    for (i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++)  
    {
        fx(temperature, pressure, time);
        results[i]=fx[i];
    }
}
```

(P/S: above is the simplified version of my real problem)
fx by itself is of course another ste of codes with equations for calculations that will give results in fx[i].

I was just wondering if I can call another function like that in a 'void' function. Just a curious question, Thanks!

Comment: Why not? What programming language are you using?

Comment: The code fragment shown lacks a function name (unless you are using a pre-standard compiler where `void` is not a keyword); the parameters would have to be K&R style with default type of `int` (you should specify their type).  You have a call to a function `fx`; you cannot also have an array called `fx`.  You don't tell the function `fx` where to store the result, so it is not clear that it can possibly know where to store the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, as long as you give the outer function a name. (This is C, or similar, right?)

Comment: yes this is C, sorry i always forget to mention the language.. okay thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and I am really curious to know why you have this question in your mind because I cannot think of any reason.

Comment: haha i dunno, who knows there are some rules that i am not aware of, just curious :D anyway my code works now so it is good!